# How to check for null value inline and throw an error in typescript?

Tags: typescript, syntax, null, null-check

In C# I can write code to check for null references and in case throw a custom exception, example:

```
var myValue = (someObject?.SomeProperty ?? throw new Exception("...")).SomeProperty;
```

In recent updates TypeScript introduced the null coalescing operator ?? but using it like the above statement produces a compilation error.
Is there some similar allowed syntax in TypeScript?

---

To clarify, the desired behavior is achieved with the following code:

```
  if(someObject?.someProperty == null) {
    throw new Error("...");
  }

  var myValue = someObject.someProperty.someProperty;
```

The code:

```
  var myValue = someObject?.someProperty.someProperty;
```

works logically ok but throws a less meaningful exception.

Comment: Shouldn't that C# version be just `var myValue = someObject?.SomeProperty ?? throw new Exception("...");` ? Or are you trying to get `someObject.SomeProperty.SomeProperty`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason for the syntax error is that `throw` is a statement, so you can't use it as the operand to an operator.

There is a [JavaScript proposal for `throw` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) working its way through the TC39 process, currently at Stage 2. If it gets to Stage 3 you can expect it will show up in TypeScript soon thereafter. (Update at the end of 2020: However, it seems to have stalled, having been [blocked in Jan 2018](https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/master/meetings/2018-01/jan-25.md) by a TC39 member who didn't think they *"...were sufficiently motivated if we have `do` expressions..."* Note that `do` expressions are still Stage 1 here at the end of 2020, but at least they were presented to TC39 [in June](https://github.com/tc39/notes/blob/master/meetings/2020-06/june-1.md#do-expressions-for-stage-2).)

With a `throw` expression, you could write this (if you want the value of `someObject.someProperty`):

```
const myValue = someObject?.someProperty ?? throw new Error("custom error here");
```

Or if you want `someObject.someProperty.someProperty` (which is what I think your C# version does):

```
const myValue = (someObject?.someProperty ?? throw new Error("custom error here")).someProperty;
```

There's a [Babel plugin for it](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-throw-expressions) you can use now. [Here's the first example above](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBBIFsCmB5ARgKycWBeGA3gL4DcAUKJLAgJ4BqAhgDYCuSM-8y6WOA_ADouSAAoAnEAAckYqDRh8-MKAAsJAdxhgkmgKJiJYgBQAiBAEsIEc2ADmcRKInTZNEwEpyleEyQCmILZGAAa0jKzs-AAkBGHMbETBnkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=stage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=) on Babel's REPL.

---

Side note: You've said you want to throw a **custom** error, but for anyone else reading this who doesn't need a custom error:

If you want `someObject.someProperty.someProperty`, with no error if `someObject` is `null`/`undefined` but getting an error if `someObject.someProperty` is `null`/`undefined`, you can do:

```
const myValue = someObject?.someProperty.someProperty;
```

With that:

- If `someObject` is `null` or `undefined`, `myValue` will get the value `undefined`
- If `someObject` is not `null` or `undefined` but `someObject.someProperty` is `null` or `undefined`, you'll get an error because we didn't use `?.` after the first `someProperty`.
- If `someObject` and `someObject.someProperty` are both not `null` or `undefined`, `myValue` will get the result of looking up `someObject.someProperty.someProperty`.

Comment: The proposal is not moving forward and it has been a long time... so I would remove the part about it moving forward soon(at the next meeting)

Comment: @Yepeekai - Yeah, last presented in 2018, blocked from consensus to move to Stage 3, and meanwhile the reason for that (`do` expressions) is still at Stage 1. But at least `do` expressions were presented at the June 2020 meeting.

Answer (score 48):

As long as TypeScript doesn't support this natively, you could write a function similar to this one:

```
function throwExpression(errorMessage: string): never {
  throw new Error(errorMessage);
}
```

which would then allow you to throw an error as expression:

```
const myString = nullableVariable ?? throwExpression("nullableVariable is null or undefined")
```

Comment: A throw helper function is an interesting approach, thanks for sharing!

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Do note that this will goof up your stacktrace a bit.

Answer (score 21):

If you're interested in throwing the error within a single line, you could wrap it in an immediately invoked function expression:

```js
const test = null ?? (() => {throw new Error("Test is nullish")})();
```

Comment: Do you know how to setup prettier so it won't reformat this into multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I bet this is what you want. I just tossed it in my `utils.ts` file:

```
export function ensuredDefined<T>(item: T | undefined, message?: string): T {
  if (item === undefined) {
    throw new Error(message ?? 'item is undefined');
  }
  return item;
}
```

Full disclosure I haven't tested this yet, but, I think this is what you want.

So instead of

```
const color = unusedColors.shift();
if (color === undefined) {
  throw new Error(...);
}
player.color = color;
```

I have

```
player.color = ensuredDefined(unusedColors.shift());
```

I bet that means you can write

```
var myValue = ensureDefined(someObject?.someProperty).someProperty
```